# Store mp3 files in a database?

Tags: android, database

I am currently creating a mobile android app in Android Studio for my church.
My app is basically a Bible which verses are linked to mp3 audio explanations from my preacher; however, I don't know whether I should save these mp3 files stored locally in the phone of the user or store them in a database.

I have been reading some things about databases and found out that SQLite is good, but stores the database locally, which is not what I want.

How can I solve this problem?
Every verse in the Bible is linked to a specific mp3 audio sermon/explanation from my preacher.

Comment: Are you saying you want to store the mp3 files online?

Comment: Yes, If that's the best choice. I don't know how heavy will all the mp3 files be, but I guess they will be very heavy and I think it's not ideal to create such heavy applications.

Comment: I'd look into using Firebase Storage. https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files . Not that difficult to get the hang of.

Answer (score 2):

Relational Databases aren't necessarily meant to store actual files. Sure, you could store BLOB binary types, but I wouldn't suggest it. That's what file servers are for. For example, Amazon S3, or Firebase Storage.

You can store the URL to a file in the database, but store the actual file on a remote system to keep your applications size small.

You can cache the resources on disk lazily as the user reads said passage, or set up a system to stream them. That'd require more effort than just downloading the whole file once per device, though

Comment: Hello, now I got the idea of what I have to do. I am going to store my mp3 files in some online storage and I am going to use the link to each mp3 file on my app, but I don't know how to do that XD. Which server do I use to accomplish such task?

Comment: I'm not much into recommending any one system. Firebase is free for a certain amount of space. Amazon S3 costs money. Both have Android and REST API capabilities. You've already gotten a link to Firebase Storage in the comments above

Answer (score 2):

I could not understand a lot from you question as there are too few details. If I understood correctly the question, the best way to implement this is to upload the mp3 you want to the server and in the android app play the file from the server (make a request to the web). In this case you will save to the database only the name of your mp3 and the link from the server to this file.

Another approach would be to convert your mp3 to base64 and save it in SQLite as a text datatype (as base64 string may have more than 256 chars long) and when needed you can decode it but it will be much slower than hosting everything to cloud

```
try {
MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
player.setDataSource("http://xty/MRESC/images/test/xy.mp3");
player.prepare();
player.start();    
} catch (Exception e) {
// TODO: handle exception
}
```

Comment: Hello, now I got the idea of what I have to do. I am going to store my mp3 files in some online storage and I am going to use the link linked to each mp3 file on my app, but I don't know how to do that XD. Which server do I use to accomplish such task?

Comment: I have no much experience in that but you can read about google firebase which was developed for mobile apps (compatible with both- ios and android). Here you can host your files, host your database, see analytics, use authentification system, etc. You can read documentation online or look for tutorials. I think this would be the best one for solving your question.

Comment: What about dropbox?

Comment: I am not sure but you can try.
(check the edit to the answer)
put your path to the sound -> link from the dropbox but anyway it would be better if you use the firebase as it is developed specially for mobile web apps